# Toggle a non selected layer via hotkey

Tags: qgis

I am trying to do some annotation in a layer (layer 1) where I draw many single polygons within a specific ROI. To do this I toggle a second layer (layer 2) on and off to compare it to the "basemap" (layer 3 at bottom). Is there a way to set a hotkey to toggle layer 2 while still being in the editing mode of layer 1 (so layer 1 is selected and I want to toggle a non-selected layer).

Comment: What is wrong with transparency or boundary-only symbology?

Comment: I want to keep layer 1 active and toggle layer 2 via a hotkey so that i can keep editing layer 1... only hotkey i found for transparency is space-bar but then i cant edit layer 1 at the same time... kicking with the mouse to remove the checkmark works but is not very efficient, unfortunately.

Comment: I got what you are asking about, I am simply providing alternatives. To be more specific "Why can't you work with transparency for the second layer, or choose a boundary-only symbology for it, instead of toggling it on and off"?

Comment: ah ok sorry I get you wrong. I am looking for changes between layer 2 and layer 3 and it is much easier to toggle it with a high frequency to detect the changes... without the direct compression is is nearly impossible to detect them.

Comment: What kind of data are we talking about? Extent, resolution, etc could be of interest.

Comment: layer 3 (basemap) ist just google satellite and layer 2 are the results of a detection algorithm that i am comparing with. But i look at it from quite some distance (zoom 1:200k) because its quite some data to go through.

Comment: You could set your `zoom factor` to something like 110 % (check the map tools under options), change the `visibility settings` of your second layer so it isn't visible at scales larger than 1:200k. Then, starting out at 1:210k you zoom in to around 190k, your second layer becomes invisible, and zoom out to 210k again (it becomes visible) etc. That's kind of a work-around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly: You can use "Toggle selected layers indepently" under the "Manage Map themes" icon (the Eye in the Layertree widget). Just select the layers which you want to be toggled, the editable layer at last, it should be the active layer. Then assign a Shortcut to "Toggle selected layers indepently" like [ALT]-X. I have produced a short animation which you will find here: https://files.wheregroup.com/index.php/s/ymwiJAn2SegPYEg